# error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de guardar un formulario en la base de datos MySQL, pero cuando trato de ejecutar para guardar, me muestra este error:

> **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

En el formulario solo tengo los campos necesarios, los otros no los pongo ya que deben quedar vacios en la BD.

Esta es mi BD

```
id | cel | token | usuario | password | direccion | r_lat | r_lng | r_ruta | jornada | sede | r_tipo | acudiente | alumno | pos | mensaje | tarifa |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |     |       |         |          |           |       |       |        |         |      |        |           |        |     |         |        |
```

Y este es el PHP que ejecuta el formulario:

```
function myapp() {
    global $connect;    

    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $r_lat = $_POST['r_lat'];
    $r_lng = $_POST['r_lng'];
    $alumno = $_POST['alumno'];
    $acudiente = $_POST['acudiente'];
    $r_cel = $_POST['r_cel'];
    $r_ruta = $_POST['r_ruta'];
    $jornada = $_POST['jornada'];   
    $sede = $_POST['sede'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $r_tipo = $_POST['r_tipo']; 
    $tarifa = $_POST['tarifa']; 

    $EncryptPassword = md5($password);

   $query = "Insert into escolarBotar 
            (
                direccion, 
                r_lat, 
                r_lng, 
                alumno, 
                acudiente, 
                r_cel, 
                r_ruta, 
                jornada, 
                sede, 
                usuario, 
                password, 
                r_tipo, 
                tarifa
            ) VALUES (
                '$direccion', 
                '$r_lat', 
                '$r_lng', 
                '$alumno', 
                '$acudiente', 
                '$r_cel', 
                '$r_ruta', 
                '$jornada', 
                '$sede', 
                '$usuario', 
                '$password', 
                '$r_tipo', 
                '$tarifa', 
                '$EncryptPassword'
            )";

    mysqli_query( $connect, $query )or die( mysqli_error( $connect ) );
    mysqli_close( $connect );
    echo " Encrypted Password Added Successfully ";
}
```

Soy nuevo en PHP y MySql aprendiendo

Comment: tu tabla tiene 16 columnas pero tu solo mandas 13 variables checa por ahí

Comment: no puedo hacerlo?, es que las otras 3 columnas deben estar vacias, esas se llenan en otro archivo

Comment: no estan empatando las variables contra las columnas por eso te marca error

Comment: comprendo, como podria hacer para enviar esas columnas a la BD y que queden vacias?, para no pedir esos datos en este formulario

Comment: salvo lo que te comenten otros usuarios y deberías esperar por mas opiniones o respuestas dejarlas desde la declaración de la base de datos como NULL para que no te sean exigidas al momento de hacer el insert

Comment: las tengo en la BD marcadas como NULL :( y aun asi las pide

Comment: entonces en tu query prueba mandando el valor DE NULL en las posiciones que a cada una le toca

Comment: intentare muchas gracias :)

Comment: El mensaje *`Column count doesn't match value count`*  indica que hay divergencia entre la cantidad de columnas que indicas en el `INSERT` y la cantidad de valores que intentas insertar. De hecho, ahora que he editado tu sentencia de inserción se puede ver perfectamente que **enumeras 13 columnas en el `INSERT` y que intentas insertar 14 valores**. Se puede apreciar que intentas insertar un último valor `$EncryptPassword` que no corresponde a ninguna columna. Si te interesa insertar ese valor debes indicar a qué columna pertenece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es queestas insertando dos veces el atributo password.
primero lo insertas asi: `'$password'` y luego lo vuelves a insertar así: `'$EncryptPassword'.`

Lo que tienes que hacer es insertar solo uno ya sea `'$password'` que guarda la contraseña normal o `'$EncryptPassword'` que la guarda encriptada, pero no se pueden guardar las dos a la vez.
y si quieres conservar en la bd la contraseña encriptada debes colocarla donde está el atributo `'$password'`.

Prueba como te digo. Espero que mi respuesta de ayude

Answer (score 2):

Veo a primera vista un par de fallos en esa sentencia.

Lo primero que estas mandando mas valores (14) que columnas seleccionadas (13).

Lo segundo no es un error de sintaxis pero me parece bastante importante, y mas si los datos vienen de un formulario que introduce un usuario, escapar los valores para evitar inyecciones de SQL.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php

Comment: el detalle de que los valores que manda y las columnas existentes no empatan ya le fue mencionado en los comentarios, la idea de colocar respuestas es una mezcla de código mas explicación; pues de otro forma esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta, te invito a leer como responder [answer]

Comment: Lo siento, soy nuevo por aqui y es mi segunda respuesta, gracias por el consejo, me leere el documento e intentare hacer mejores preguntas y respuestas. De todo y de todos se aprende.